# how to write raw sql in rails scope?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, datagrid, scope

I want to get a query result by using the sql below:

```
select * 
from (select id, account_uuid, type, content, reference_id, messages.created_at as msg_time 
      from messages 
      where content IS NOT NULL 
      order by created_at desc) a 
inner join accounts 
on accounts.uuid = a.account_uuid 
group by a.account_uuid 
order by a.id desc;
```

and I wrote a scope in grids/messages.rb like this :

```
class Messages
  include Datagrid
  scope do
    Account.group(:uuid).joins("select * from (select id, account_uuid, type, content, reference_id, messages.created_at as msg_time from messages where content IS NOT NULL order by created_at desc)")
            .order("message_id desc")
  end
end
```

and I got the sql syntax error (obviously).
Please tell me how to convert the sql above to some codes for scope. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the scope is not the right thing to use here for your codes.
you'd better use an class method for the convenience.